# How to change this geometric progression into a direct one

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the progression:

$$u_0 = 5$$

$$ u_{n+1} = 3- 0.5u_n \space ( n = 1,2,...)$$

I want to change this into a 'direct' progression, so I tried:

$$ 5 \cdot -0.5^n + 3$$ but this actually fails for $n=0$. How can I edit this so it also holds for $n=0$?

Comment: (1) Did you mean $\,u_{n+1}=3-0.5u_n\,$ ? Because if you did then this is **not** a geometric progression, and (2) what is a "direct progression"?

Comment: @DonAntonio For the one you need to know the previous term, for the other you can immediately plug in a number if you understand what I mean.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what you mean: a progression $\,u_1,u_2,...\,$ is geometric iff for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ , we have that $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=q=\;\text{a constant}$$ I can't see how yours fulfills this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, we do not have a geometric progression. Instead, we have the recurrence 
$$u_{n+1}=3-(0.5)u_n,$$
with $u_0=5$. We want an explicit formula for $u_n$.

There are many techniques for dealing with this sort of problem. We use one of the basic ones.  Let $u_n=c+y_n$, where we will choose $c$ to make the recurrence nicer. Then our recurrence can be rewritten as
$$c+y_{n+1}=3-(0.5)(c+y_n)$$
or equivalently
$$y_{n+1}=3-(0.5)c-c -(0.5)y_n.$$
To make the constant term in the recurrence disappear, we choose $c=2$. 
We arrive at the recurrence
$$y_{n+1}=(-0.5)y_n,$$
with $y_0= 3$. This has the solution $y_n=3(-0.5)^n$, and therefore we get
$$u_n=2+3(-0.5)^n$$